# Display Emoji in Python's console

Tags: python, console, char, codec, emoji

I wonder if it's possible to print Emojis in a Python 3 console on Windows. Actually, to avoid the following error:

```
codec can't encode character '\U0001f44d' in position 10: character maps to  
<undefined>
```

I've used:

```
import emoji as moji
print(moji.emojize('Python is :thumbsup:', use_aliases=True).encode('unicode-
escape'))
```

which is, *as expected*, printing the right `character:U0001f44d` without any `exception`.

Comment: *Which* operating system, which *Python* console, do you mean *Windows* console window or something?

Comment: Because otherwise the answer is **yes**, `>>> print('\U0001f44d')` -> `` if you happen to run this on Linux and Python 3.5.2 and Konsole and so on.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yes, i use `Windows` as `OS`. is this the main reason? if `yes`, why `Windows` appears to an hindrance here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Windows command prompt has a lot of limitations with regards to Unicode characters, especially those outside the basic multilingual plane(BMP, or U+0000 to U+FFFF).  The command prompt defaults to a legacy OEM encoding (cp437 on US Windows) and has limited font support for characters outside the localized encoding. Find a Python IDE that has good support for UTF-8.

One quick-and-dirty way to see a wide variety of Unicode characters is to write to a file and leverage the browser:

```
import os
with open('test.htm','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    f.write('\U0001f44d')
os.startfile('test.htm')
```

This displays [image: thumbs up] in the latest Chrome browser on my Windows 10 system.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: good idea to use utf-8-sig. Had to google for a quite a while to find some info on that

Comment: Yes, if a file has a UTF-8-encoded BOM (byte order mark) most browsers will use UTF-8 to decode the file for display.  That's what `utf-8-sig` ensures is written to the file.

Answer (score 7):

First install emoji module ---  pip install emoji

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up:'))
```

This code is working in Anaconda Jupyter environment...

[image]